# Better ruby terminal coloring library

Tags: ruby, terminal, ansi-colors

There are plenty of coloring libraries: colored, term-ansicolor.
But is there any which can do this:

```
puts "#{'hello'.red} world!".bold
```

And `world!` should be bold.

To make it clear, I want to get this:

```
"\e[1m\e[31mhello\e[0m\e[1m world!\e[0m"
```

or better even this (just shorter):

```
"\e[1;31mhello\e[0;1m world!\e[0m"
```

instead of this:

```
"\e[1m\e[31mhello\e[0m world!\e[0m"
```

Comment: The API you are proposing doesn't make sense.  How would the library know when to reset the colors/styles?

Comment: @cam: It surely makes sense. What do you expect from html `<strong><span style="color:red">hello</span> world!</strong>`? I want same thing in bash and I was just trying to know if there is already such library and if not I'll write my own.

Comment: your HTML example is not equivalent.  What is the expected output of `"red #{"green".green} red".red`?

Comment: @cam: Why not equivalent?? I want all string to be bold and `hello` to be red (and bold as it is part of string). For your example html equivalent is `<span style="color:red">red <span style="color:green">green</span> red</span>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As there is none, I wrote my own, <strike>with blackjack and hookers</strike> smart one — [smart_colored](https://rubygems.org/gems/smart_colored)

```
gem install smart_colored
```

and run

```
require 'smart_colored/extend'
# without extend you'll need to use 'string'.colored.red

puts "#{'hello'.red} world!".bold
```

Answer (score 0):

The lib is called [Highline](http://highline.rubyforge.org/doc/)
It has a `color` method: `say("This should be <%= color('bold', BOLD) %>!")`
Which can be easily used to implement `String#bold`.

Comment: @tig, read the answer one more time. What you asked for is a String#bold method. Daniel provided a way for you to make one. This would work for String#red, etc, too.

Comment: @Mark: I told in my question that I don't need simple coloring library (with such problem google would help me with pleasure) as they all do same error — they don't understand nesting. Adapting Daniel's code gave me same result as colored (`HighLine.new.color("#{HighLine.new.color('hello', HighLine::RED)} world!", HighLine::BOLD)`): ` world!` is not bold

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using highline I made a gem that extends colors and provides helpers such as:

```
say_bold 'this is bold text'
```

https://github.com/bonzofenix/highline-color