# colored text with highlighted data via colored gem

Tags: ruby, string, colors

I am trying to achieve multi colored text with the colored gem in ruby.

Basically I want to set a base color for the text, but highlight specific details in another color while still keeping all the other text in the base color.

For example if I do something like:

```
puts "Found #{book_title.yellow} and it has #{chapters.to_s.yellow} chapters".green
```

I would of expected that the entire phrase would be green except for the book title and number of chapters which should be yellow.

Instead the results are that "Found" is green, book title is yellow, "and it has" is white (no color), chapters is yellow, and "chapters" is white (no color).

It simply appears that appending .green to the surrounding string doesn't re-add the color codes after a color change when using #{} to insert data.

I want to build this functionality into a info function like so:

```
  def info(message)
    time_stamp = "[#{Time.new.strftime("%H:%M:%S")}]"
    puts "#{time_stamp} Info: #{message}".green
  end
```

So that when I call it like so:

```
info "Found #{book_title.yellow} and it has #{chapters.to_s.yellow} chapters"
```

It will print the entire statement in green with highlighted text in yellow as described above.

Is this possible without breaking the string into substrings and concatting them, or specifying a hard coded list of arguments to the info function (the number of highlighted texts is dynamic). Is there a VA_LIST type like in C's printf I could use?

I wouldn't mind calling the function as:

```
info "Found %s and it has %d chapters", book_title.yellow, chapters.to_s.yellow
```

or something similar. But I would still need to figure out a way to set the color codes for each segment of text and concat them together.

Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419072/better-ruby-terminal-coloring-library

Comment: Jordan, same question yes. smart_colored solved the problem. Thanks for the link.